# Prove that the problem of CFG producing epsylon is decidable

Tags: turing-machines, computability, context-free, decidability

I have been given the following problem and was wondering if my solution is correct (taken from the textbook exercise in the book Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Martin Sipser):
Given $$\text{A}_{\text{εCFG}} =\{\langle G\rangle \mid G\text{ is a CFG }\text{that generates ε}\}$$ prove that $\text{A}_{\text{εCFG}}$ is decidable.

The following is my solution:

```
On input <G>:
1. Build a PDA P such that L(P)=L(G)
2. If the starting state is an accepting state accept
3. Follow each epsylon transition from the starting state and if it reaches an accept state accept
4. If none accept state is reached reject
```

Can this be considered a valid solution?

Edit:

There may be a better approach which is the following:

```
On input <G>:
1. Build a PDA P such that L(P)=L(G)
2. Execute APDA on input <G, ε>
3. Return the output
```

Comment: $G$ is not used in the set restriction (you use $A$ instead). Maybe that's a typo?

Comment: @Tonita yes that's a typo I am sorry, I will edit it immediately!

Comment: In the algorithm, you forgot the termination condition in the case "none final state is reached". If we simply follow all the transitions from the reached states, the algorithm will loop, since for example the $\varepsilon$-transition from $s_1$ to $s_2$ can push $A$ to the stack, and the transition from $s_2$ to $s_1$ pops $A$. So, we need some set to be saturated (monotonically grow up to a finite bound) to terminate.

Comment: @Tonita so I should replace line 4 with "If none final state is reached, reject" am I correct? Thank you for the help!

Comment: No, accept state = final state, that's simply synonimic to what you have. You should add a condition when to terminate if none accept state is reached so far.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I see it now, the idea would be to delete the transition who have already been seen correct?

Comment: You can also work directly with the grammar. This might give a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus oh ok, thank you! I am still wondering if my solutions are correct though, I am preparaing for an exam and my professor told me that it does not matter for the exam the efficiency of the algorithm, so I am just trying to focus on making correct algorithms!

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W. I am asking here because nobody else replies and it could be helpful to other students in the future who appear to have the same question, I agree with you that in this case the answer could be a yes/no, but I disagree with the fact that it won't help me, I am studying hard for an exam and having these type of replies would help me find out if I am prepared or not (and fix my solutions), I also believe that these type of questions are useful to other students who find themselves having to solve the same problem, I will try to edit the question in a better way!